# Basic Probability proof question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing

I have to proof the following statement:
Show that there cannot exist three events $A, B, C$ satisfying
$P(A ∩ B) = 1/8$

and

$P(B|A) = 1/2P(A)=1/3P(B)$

Hint try to compute $P(A\cup B)$

Why is event $C$ specified or is this just a typo?
If so how to proof this (without event $C$)?

Comment: When trying to prove that something can’t exist, it is often useful to try to use proof by contradiction.  So assume the contrary of the proposition, and try to arrive at some sort of contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:
$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{\frac18}{P(A)}=\frac12 P(A) \Rightarrow P(A)=\frac12;\\
\frac12 P(A)=\frac13P(B) \Rightarrow P(B)=\frac34;\\
P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=\frac12+\frac34-\frac18=\frac98>1.$$
So, it does not matter whether $C$ is given or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think event $C$ is probably a typo, although the question still technically makes sense with it. You can show that the $A$ and $B$ described are impossible. And then it will also be the case that $A,$ $B$ and some unspecified and unimportant $C$ are impossible.

You have enough information to calculate $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ and then you can use the hint to show there's a contradiction.

Comment: Yes you can express $P(A),P(B)$ in $P(B|A) $and calculate $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A and B)$ but this doesn't run into a contradiction. The only thing I got is the quadratic equation $2x^2=1/8$ and this is perfectly consitent

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising I think you can find numbers for $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. Not sure what $x$ is for you.